# How can I prevent people from pasting links to documents?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I designed an MVC app with authorization that works great. In my app, a user can click a link to view a document.  The document displays in another tab.  If the user saves that link, logs out, and comes back (without logging in), they can paste the link into the browser to see the document.  They can also change the parameters in the link to view documents that may or may not be associated with their account.  The link is create as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "CertificatePDF", "Documents", new { wo_nbr = Model.id}, new { target = "_blank" })
```

This creates the following link:
http://xxx.yyy.com/Documents/CertificatePDF?wo_nbr=1000462209

How can I prevent users from viewing/changing documents unless they are logged into the app?

Comment: Have you added a `[Authorize]` attrribute to your `CertificatePDF` action?

Comment: Yes I have.  When I do that, the documents won't open from within my app either. I think the problem is related to the fact that I'm opening a new tab in the browser... but don't know what to do about it...

Comment: Something else is going on then, if your users are logged in, they should be able to download the pdf with the Authorize attrib. With the attribute in place, do your breakpoints get hit?

Comment: I retested, and now it works! Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: How do I mark a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your `CertificatePDF` action. This should require users to be authenticated. You can add the attribute to your controller class if you want everything to require authentication. Also for the opposite you can add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to bypass authentication.